# CSS android browser does not allow to scroll content

Tags: android, html, ios, css, background

On my website (www.wetter-goch.de) I'm showing current weather information. for mobile device i added the overflow-y css attribute to the div-container.

This is working like charm on iOS' Safari, but on Android the site does not allow to scroll through the content. additionally my background image is not scaled to the viewport-size of the mobile-device.

I'm creating the background by the following css

```
<style>

html { 
  background: url(<?= DataSource::getCurrentTimeLapsePath() ?>) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

</style>
```

HTML-Viewport Meta-Tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Sidebar-CSS of the hole website...

```
.leftsidebar {

    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:-1;

    width: 280px; 
    height: 100%;

    padding: 10px;

    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);

    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Related media queries

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 1000px) { 

    .leftsidebar {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .rightsidebar {
        display: none;
    }

    .radar { 
        display: none; 
    }

    .statistics { 
        display: none; 
    }

}
```

Hope anybody could help me solving this.

Comment: What's the HTML code? Please provide html to determine what's going on. Are you even running a media query?

Comment: @Ravenous see edited question, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the media type that's specified you need to query the page to determine the style sheet to load.  You'll need to added a media attribute to the style sheet that is for mobile "handheld". It'll then load the correct sheet on Android.

`<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="print.css"media="handheld">
</head>`

Comment: So i would have to manage multiple stylesheets? but why is this working on iOS but not on Android?

Comment: The viewport mets tag manages the size of the page for iOS. and iOS heavily relies on that viewport meta tag to make the page correct for those screens. Android doesn't use the viewport unless wrapped in an actual application.

Comment: That's really weird... is there any other way due to multiple files?

Comment: Not that I'm currently aware of. To be honest though having multiple sheets turns out to be better when the sheet starts to get very large. Why can you have another style sheet?

Comment: @DanielBocksteger try loading the same CSS file but using the media query then it should find the `@media` tags that are listed in that single file.